# Sharing Javascript variables between function

Tags: javascript, random, scope

So I have a few variables that I need to use within two separate functions.
The first function essentially uses the variables to calculate and then display something (a conjugated verb). The second function uses the variables to see if the user's answers were correct, and changes some HTML styling accordingly.

However, these variables are calculated randomly, like this:

```
function randomIntFromInterval(min,max) {
return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min); }

var tense = randomIntFromInterval(1, 6);
var person = randomIntFromInterval(1, 3);
var number = randomIntFromInterval(1, 2);
var voice = randomIntFromInterval(1, 2);
```

I can't declare them as global variables outside a function, because they need to be recalculated every time the first function is called. I can't declare them in their own function and call it inside the original two functions, because both of the functions needs the same values.

How can I do this?

Comment: Pass them to the other function as arguments when calling the other function.  Or, make them properties of an object and pass the object as an argument.   This is what function arguments are for.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're asking how to pass a structure of values between two functions. What you (probably) don't want to do is pass each one individually, although that is an option if you only have a few and they come from different sources. If they come from the same, or similar, sources then you can use an object with named keys like:

```
function randomIntFromInterval(min,max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min); 
}

function getRandomSections() {
  return {
    tense: randomIntFromInterval(1, 6),
    person: randomIntFromInterval(1, 3),
    number: randomIntFromInterval(1, 2),
    voice: randomIntFromInterval(1, 2)
  };
}

function doSomethingWithSections(sections) {
  // do some things
}

function doSomethingElseWithSections(sections) {
  // do some things
}

// Put it all together
var sections = getRandomSections();
doSomethingWithSections(sections);
doSomethingElseWithSections(sections); // using the same values in a second function
```

If they came from unrelated places, I would suggest using individual params (as suggested by @jfriend00 in the comments) and doing:

```
function doSomethingWith(tense, person, number, voice) {
  // do some things
}

doSomethingWithSections(getTense(), getPerson(), getNumber(), getVoice());
```

If you want to make the list of fields somewhat dynamic, you can make `getRandomSections` data-driven like:

```
function getSections(names, cb) {
  var obj = {};
  names.forEach(function (name) {
    obj[name] = cb(x, y);
  });
  return obj;
}

// Used as
getSections(['tense', 'person', 'number', 'voice'], randomIntFromInterval);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, these don't work. I have two separate functions that need to get _the same_ values from these random variables. I need to calculate the random values once, then have those values available to two functions. Unless I'm missing something, your solutions seem to work only for passing the data from one function to one other function.

Comment: @TheFirstQuestion - If you have an associated element, like the question element, you can use the [element.dataset](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/10/using-data-attributes-in-javascript-and-css/) to store those values in relation to the question.

Comment: @TheFirstQuestion edited to show how you would go about that. It's super simple once you have the values in a variable.

Comment: @JaredFarrish for most purposes that is incredibly over-complicated and often inappropriate (you don't want to store any complex data on an element).

Comment: @ssube Thank you, that's much clearer. But is there a way I could run the functions separately? I was hoping to attach the functions to two separate HTML buttons.

Comment: If you've prepared the data early on (when the first button is hit or when the page loads) and attached it to the global scope (the self object) or your top-level object, then both buttons can use it.

Comment: @ssube I'm sorry, I'm pretty new to coding. How exactly would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Cant you do something like this-

```
function randomIntFromInterval(min,max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min); 
}

function f1(t, p, n, v){ //arguments for function
    //something
}
function f2(t, p, n, v){
    //something
}

function main(){
    var tense = randomIntFromInterval(1, 6);
    var person = randomIntFromInterval(1, 3);
    var number = randomIntFromInterval(1, 2);
    var voice = randomIntFromInterval(1, 2);

    f1(tense, person, number, voice);
    f2(tense, person, number, voice);
}

main();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no, as I need the functions to run independently of each other, but thank you for the answer!